# Gatsby set background-image CSS-In-JS (Emotion)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby, emotion

No `background-image` visible with the setup below. As a debugging step, I have tried setting `background: pink` within `const background` and this does work, confirming that `emotion` is running correctly.

When opening `React Dev Tools extension` I can see `background-image: url(../images/page_backgroundgradient.png), url(../images/page_background.png);`applied without an error.

What could my issue be please?

My file structure looks like below:

```
frontend/
  src/
    images/
      page_background.png
      page_backgroundgradient.png
    pages/
      index.js
```

My `index.js`that I am trying to add a background image to.

```
...
import { css, Global } from "@emotion/core"


const background = css`
  background-image: url(../images/page_backgroundgradient.png), url(../images/page_background.png);
`
<div css={background}>
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the full path to the file at CSS `url()` function?

Comment: @guest271314 That would be: `url(src/images/page_background.png)`? Because if so, no luck!

Comment: That is not a full path.

Comment: @guest271314 I tried `url(/Users/username/reponame/frontend/src/images/page_background.png)`, which I believe is full path. No luck either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls

Comment: @guest271314 I'm sorry, I'm very confused. Do you mind spelling it out for me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188939/discussion-between-isaacsultan-and-guest271314).

Comment: images in your `src` folders are not copied when build, so the path you use doesn't point to a real image file. You are likely to find the path to the built image in your graphql query though, let me know if you're still stuck on this.

Comment: Hi @DerekNguyen, I am actually not doing a graphql query to get the image file. My usage seems very similar to the 2nd example here https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-images-fonts-files/ . So yes, still stuck!

Comment: Alright, I posted a few ways to get images, let me know if it helps

Comment: I just realized you were the same person asking the other question in `emotion` tag -- hope my comment helped you over there too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So as stated in the link you posted in the comment, there's multiple ways to include image/assets with gatsby:

1. Query the image from `graphql`
2. `import` the image, get path
3. Copy the image to `static` directory

---

### Set up

Say you have a component like this:

```
// src/pages/sample.js

import React from 'react'
import { css } from '@emotion/core'

export default () => <div css={css`
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: url( ... );
`} />
```

### Query it

#### PublicURL

If you're using any of the default starters, it's likely that your `src/images` folder has been set up with `gatsby-source-file-system` so Gatsby know about your images. Say you know the name of the file, you can query it like so:

```
{
//       ⇣ `base` is file name with extension.
  file (base: { eq: "image.png" }) {
    publicURL
  }
}
```

As described in the link, querying the field `publicURL` will give you the path to the file name:

```
export default ({ data }) => <div css={css`
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: url(${data.file ? data.file.publicURL : 'your/fallback.png'});
`} />

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    file(base: { eq: "image.png" }) {
      publicURL
    }
  }
`
```

#### ImageSharp

Gatsby usually comes with `sharp`, which allows you to transform images & more. For a simple example, this query resize the image to 200px width:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    file(base: { eq: "image.png" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fixed(width: 200) {
          src
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

And you can access it at `data.file.childImageSharp.fixed.src`.

### Import the image

Let webpack handle it:

```
import myImagePath from '../relative/path/to/image.png';

export default () => <div css={css`
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: url(${myImagePath});
`} />
```

---

### Copy it to `static` directory

Create a directory named `static` at your root folder, unless there's one already. Copy your image into it:

```
root
  |--src
  `--static
       `--image.png
```

All files in static will be copy directly to build, so you can link to the image like this:

```
export default () => <div css={css`
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: url(/image.png);
`} />
```

If you're using `pathPrefix` in `gatsby-config.js`, import `withPrefix` from `gatsby` and wrap it around the image path.

---

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4r76xpz3qw?fontsize=14) for the first 2 methods.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Dejell it's also the least ideal way to do it. What issue are you running into?

Comment: upon build, the picture is not being copied to static folder